# Excel Lag Two Group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| STUDENT | TIME | CLASS | SCORE | WANT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 13 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | B | 4 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | A | 11 | -2 |
| 1 | 2 | B | 9 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | A | 8 | -3 |
| 2 | 2 | B | 16 | NULL |
| 2 | 3 | B | 6 | -10 |
| 2 | 4 | A | 7 | NULL |
| 2 | 4 | B | 6 | 0 |

I have XLSX file with STUDENT, TIME, CLASS, SCORE. I wish to calculate WANT which does this:

For every STUDENT and CLASS, calculate the difference in SCORE from TIME(X) TO TIME(X-1).

for STUDENT=1, TIME=2,CLASS=B equals to 5 because it is (9-4)

I try this with no success:

```
=IF(A3=A2 & C3=C2, OFFSET(D3, -1, 0), "")
```

Comment: Shouldnt 7th WANT be -10 instead of NULL?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,C$2:C2,C2)>1,D2-SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A2,B:B,B2-1,C:C,C2),"Null")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is far from the best approach, but it works.
If using helper column is not a problem, you can make additional column for `VLOOKUP` (see column "Helper1") with formula `=TEXTJOIN("-",,A2:C2)`.
Now use `VLOOKUP` to find value `TEXTJOIN("-",,A2,B2-1,C2)` in that column. Formula in "WANT" column: `IFNA(E2-VLOOKUP(TEXTJOIN("-",,A2,B2-1,C2),$D$2:$E$10,2,FALSE),"NULL")`

Result:
[image]

Comment: My honest opinion: Stay away from concatenated values. Not just this specific use-case, but in general. Oversight on data becomes tricky and chances are false positives will start invalidate your output without you noticing it. What if there is a student 11 in class A? If you must concatenate columns, then use delimiters.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Edited to have separators. Will definitely try to avoid concatenation in future where it is avoidable.